# Powershell - Write-Log message is returned with output variable

Tags: powershell, build, teamcity, powershell-2.0

I have written powershell script that populates a variable from a function (written in another script). The problem is, that the **Write-Log** output from the second script is also returned along with it. Any idea how to resolve the same??

Here is a snippet of my code:

> Script 1

```
$version = Get-Version -Path $Path
```

> Script 2

```
Write-Log -Message ("##teamcity[progressMessage Setting up the default version) -Debug
...
...
...
...
return $Version
```

Now, the Issue is that from the second script, the output I am getting the following:

```
$version = #Write-Log -Message ("##teamcity[progressMessage Setting up the default version) 1.0.0.0.0
```

Comment: Why in 2nd script write-log is commented (#)?

Comment: I'm confused, could you try to be a bit more clear about what you have and what you are trying get. Posting more of the actual code would help.

Comment: Sry, that was commented by mistake. Edited the code now

Answer (score 1):

Any statement that produces some value is returned from script or function. So the following code produces 2 values: directory info and string 'succ'

```
function test {
    mkdir c:\sotest
    'succ'
}
```

You even don't need to call `return`. The `return` statement is useful, when you need to just return the value and exit the function/script.

In the test example if you don't want to return directory info, you can

```
mkdir .. | out-null
mkdir .. > $null
[void](mkdir ..)
```